# Grep specific pattern from different columns of line using bash

Tags: bash, design-patterns

I have some results, and I need to get the pattern like: "./.", "0/1", "0/0".
How can I do this using bash?
Thanks.

```
G   A   89.43   PASS    AB=0.427;AC=2;AF=0.33;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=-1.468;DP=12;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HRun=1;HaplotypeScore=0.6373;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=0.536;QD=12.78;ReadPosRankSum=1.134;SB=-26.82;set=variant2    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./. 0/1:2,3:5:67.41:102,0,67    ./. 0/1:1,1:2:25.53:26,0,36 0/0:5,0:5:15.05:0,15,200
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retrieve only the columns which have a slash in them?

Comment: Also -- should `13/20` be returned as 4 digits, or as `3/2`? Or not at all?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
grep -o './.' <<< "$results"
```

Comment: thanks. looks good. but how can I make every 5 ./. in the same line?

Comment: @wang, did you try it? that's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl.

```
echo "G   A   89.43   PASS    AB=0.427;AC=2;AF=0.33;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=-1.468;DP=12;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HRun=1;HaplotypeScore=0.6373;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=0.536;QD=12.78;ReadPosRankSum=1.134;SB=-26.82;set=variant2    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./. 0/1:2,3:5:67.41:102,0,67    ./. 0/1:1,1:2:25.53:26,0,36 0/0:5,0:5:15.05:0,15,200" \
  | perl -lne 'my @matches = m{(./.)}g; print join "\n", @matches;'
```

This returns:

```
./.
0/1
./.
0/1
0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'G;:a;/^\n,*/{s///;;b};s/^\(.\/.\)\(.*\)/\2,\1/;ta;s/.//;ba' file
./.,0/1,./.,0/1,0/0
```